# Why sign session cookies?

Tags: cookies, session-management, node.js

I'm using express-session middleware to store sessions on the server. The client's browser gets a cookie with the session ID. A secret is required in the configuration; it is used to sign the session ID cookie.

https://github.com/expressjs/session#secret

What's the value of this signature? What's the threat it's mitigating? Even if a threat actor knows a session ID, they have no access to the session store. The odds of guessing someone else's ID should be astronomical.

Comment: This is mentioned as a now closed issue in the Expressjs github... https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/68

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, the software permits developers to provide their own session IDs, which (because people are often bad at security) might be short and/or predictable. The signature is thus added to create a minimum amount of entropy in the token to prevent guessing or brute-forcing another user's token if the token itself is low-entropy.

Or, as you put it, the odds [against] guessing somebody else's session ID *should* be astronomical... but you probably generate session IDs using something like "16 bytes from a CSPRNG" and some people instead use `Random.nextInt()` or even just an incrementing counter or something. In those situations, guessing or even brute-forcing other IDs is pretty easy, so the token is signed as, essentially, a way to "mix in" the entropy of the secret with the (possibly low) entropy of the token without revealing the secret itself.

Obviously, if both the token and the secret itself are guessable and the attacker realizes this, this will still be insecure. But, at some level, there's nothing you can do about a dev who is obstinate about being insecure. No matter how many footguns you take away, somebody will nail themselves to the floor with a pencil.